# How can i connect https signalr hub on flutter

Tags: flutter, signalr

I work signalr_core package on flutter. Hub connection perfect with http communication but it can't work with https. I'm getting error like this.

> I/flutter (13925): Starting HubConnection.
> I/flutter (13925): Starting connection with transfer format 'TransferFormat.text'.
> I/flutter (13925): Sending negotiation request: https://url:2600/notify/negotiate.
> I/flutter (13925): Selecting transport 'HttpTransportType.serverSentEvents'.
> I/flutter (13925): (SSE transport) Connecting.
> I/flutter (13925): SSE connected to https://url:2600/notify?id=UvR4grgdVXNVH0cd4-Wqzw&access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9zeXN0ZW0iOiIxZDMyZGUwYi02MzQ5LTQzNGYtZmMxZi0wOGRhMTNlZjc0NjUiLCJuYW1laWQiOiIzNmYwYjcyOC01NjA4LTQ3MGItYjQ1ZS0zMWI1YjY4YTA0MTUiLCJuYmYiOjE2NTI0NDgzMjgsImV4cCI6MTY1NTA0MDMyOCwiaWF0IjoxNjUyNDQ4MzI4fQ.1nsEoT33fdsV00Mrukq963YGwGsgM4xUtH6CHS1oPKw
> I/flutter (13925): The HttpConnection connected successfully.
> I/flutter (13925): Sending handshake request.
> I/flutter (13925): (SSE transport) sending data. String data of length '32'.
> I/flutter (13925): (SSE transport) request complete. Response status: 200.
> I/flutter (13925): Using HubProtocol 'json'.
> I/flutter (13925): HttpConnection.stopConnection(Exception: Failed to connect to https://url:2600/notify?id=UvR4grgdVXNVH0cd4-Wqzw) called while in state ConnectionState.connected.
> I/flutter (13925): Connection disconnected with error 'Exception: Failed to connect to https://url:2600/notify?id=UvR4grgdVXNVH0cd4-Wqzw'.
> I/flutter (13925): HubConnection.connectionClosed(Exception: Failed to connect to https://url:2600/notify?id=UvR4grgdVXNVH0cd4-Wqzw) called while in state HubConnectionState.connecting.
> I/flutter (13925): Hub handshake failed with error 'Exception: Failed to connect to https://url:2600/notify?id=UvR4grgdVXNVH0cd4-Wqzw' during start(). Stopping HubConnection.
> I/flutter (13925): Call to HttpConnection.stop(Exception: Failed to connect to https://url:2600/notify?id=UvR4grgdVXNVH0cd4-Wqzw) ignored because the connection is already in the disconnected state.
> I/flutter (13925): HubConnection failed to start successfully because of error '{Exception: Failed to connect to https://url:2600/notify?id=UvR4grgdVXNVH0cd4-Wqzw.toString()}'.
> E/flutter (13925): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: Failed to connect to https://url:2600/notify?id=UvR4grgdVXNVH0cd4-Wqzw
> E/flutter (13925):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed by https://github.com/jamiewest/signalr_core/issues/89#issuecomment-1134860677 with this ref. He said bug in package. If you send token manually it'll be work